# How to store output of a shell script inside a variable in conky?

Tags: linux, conky

So I'm getting to get the CPU core temperature using `sensors` command.

Inside conky, I wrote

```
$Core 0 Temp:$alignr${execi 1 sensors | grep 'Core 0' | awk {'print $3'}} $alignr${execibar 1 sensors | grep 'Core 0' | awk {'print $3'}}
```

Each second I'm running the exact same command `sensors | grep 'Core 0' | awk {'print $3'}` in two places for exact same output. Is there is a way to hold the output inside a variable and use that variable in place of the commands.

Answer (score 1):

`conky` does not have user variables. What you can do instead is call lua from conky to do this for you. The lua language is usually built-in to conky by default, so you need only put some code in a file, include the file in the conky setup file, and call the function. For example, these shell commands will create a test:

```sh
cat >/tmp/.conkyrc <<\!
conky.config = {
    lua_load = '/tmp/myfunction.lua',
    minimum_height = 400,
    minimum_width = 600,
    use_xft = true,
    font = 'Times:size=20',
};
conky.text = [[
 set ${lua myfunction t ${execi 1 sensors | awk '/^Core 0/{print 0+$3}'}}°C
 get ${lua myfunction t}°C ${lua_bar myfunction t}
]]
!
cat >/tmp/myfunction.lua <<\!
vars = {}
function conky_myfunction(varname, arg)
 if(arg~=nil)then vars[varname] = conky_parse(arg) end
 return vars[varname]
end
!
conky -c /tmp/.conkyrc -o
```

In the `myfunction.lua` file, we declare a function `myfunction()` (which needs to be prefixed `conky_` so we can call it from conky). It takes 2 parameters, the name of a variable, and a conky expression.  It calls `conky_parse()` to evaluate the expression, and saves the value in a table `vars`, under the name provided by the caller. It then returns the resulting value to the caller. If no expression was given, it will return the previous value.

In the `conky.text` the line beginning `set` calls `myfunction` in lua with the arbitrary name of a variable, `t`, and the `execi` sensors expression to evaluate, save, and return. The line beginning `get` calls `myfunction` to just get the value.

`lua_bar` is similar to `exec_bar`, but calls a lua function, see `man conky`. However, it expects a number without the leading `+` that `exec_bar` accepts, so I've changed the `awk` to return this, and have added the `°C` to the conky text instead.

Comment: Looks good, but it'd probably be better to name the function something like `conky_var` or `conky_variable` rather than `conky_myfunction` to make it's purpose more easily distinguishable in the conky config file.

Comment: Sure. I just used *myfunction* as a place holder to make it stand out in the code, and would expect the user to replace this with a name more meaningful to them.